# ui-sref link not working on ipad

Tags: angularjs, ipad, cordova, angular-ui-router

My (phonegap) application is working fine in my browser (Chrome+Ripple) as well on my android tablet. However the link isn't working anymore when build the app with xCode and run it on the iPad.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(){..});
```

shows an error:

```
config: Object
data: ""
headers: function (c) {a||(a=vc(b));return c?a[D(c)]||null:a;}
status: 404
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

I guess *404* means "state not found"?

Route:

```
.state('seminar', {
    url: "/seminar/{id}",
    views: {
        'nav@':  { templateUrl: "views/navigation/main.html" },
        'main@': { templateUrl: "views/seminars/main.html" },
        'side@': { templateUrl: "views/seminars/side.html" }
    }
})
```

View:

```
<a href ui-sref="seminar({ id: seminarCtrl.seminar.id})">Start</a>
```

On the login-form,

```
ng-submit()
```

is working fine.

I couldn't find any other questions related to this problem. Could there be a problem with iOS and ui-sref/ui-router?

Thank you in advance.

**-- Update 1 --**

Here is a screenshot of the error message thrown by the *$stateChangeError* function:

[image: Errormessage]

Comment: 404 should mean the browser couldnt find the html file

Comment: It is working on the browser and on the android device, but not on the iPad.

Comment: can you check your browser console for error (can be done by mac's safari)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an answer why it is working in the browser but not on iOS, but i managed to find a solution.

My new router:

```
.state('seminar', {
        url: "/seminar/{seminar_id}",
        views: {
            'nav@':  { templateUrl: "views/navigation/main.html" },
            'main@': { templateUrl: "views/seminars/main.html" },
            'side@': { templateUrl: "views/contact/side.html" }
        }
    })
    .state('seminar.course', {
        url: "/course/{course_id}",
        views: {
            'main@': { templateUrl: "views/courses/main.html" },
            'side@': { templateUrl: "views/courses/side.html" }
        }
    })
```

The problem was hidden in the second route. At first I had written

```
url: "seminar/{seminar_id}/course/{course_id}",
```

which lead to a wrong url

```
/seminar/1/seminar/1/course/5
```

It worked for iOS after removing the first part of the url.

Also to mention, the seminar_id will be handed to the second route automatically and is available in the $stateParams.

Hopefully someone can use this information.