# Angular A tags not working on iOS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some basic A tags in a menu, I have used UI routers ui-sref="" to add the href attribute.

The HTML generated:

```
<a target="_self" ui-sref="news" href="/news">News</a>
```

When clicking this link on a desktop it works every time, but for mobile, it is largely hit and miss, although the tags css hover state does get activated on tap.

I have HTML5 mode enabled, and read that adding target="_self" to the link would fix the issue for this setup, with no luck.

Does anyone know of any reason this would happen?

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521433/ui-sref-link-not-working-on-ipad

Comment: no errors thrown at all, its as if it is just being ignored, I have added an ng-click to see if that gets fired also, which it does not